# How to disable downloading of Confluence attachments during business hours

Tags: hide, attachment, confluence

[Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/confluence) wiki has an excellent method for storing attachments where hundreds of files can be uploaded to a single page. Each page is like a folder where the page content and attachments are in the folder. Attachments can be downloaded by going to Tools > Attachments and selecting the file to download. To make things easier there is an option to **Download All**. This zips all of the files up and sends it to the user who sees it as a .zip with a random name.

There is a problem with pages with large numbers of attachments for which users download during working hours causing heavy load on the server. A method for disabling the download function during business hours or disabling large zip files from being created during business hours is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `confluence/confluence/pages/viewattachments.vm` and change the logic for displaying the *Download all* link so that it only displays outside of buiness hours.

Code to add:

```
        ## Only display Download All link during business hours ##
        #set ($tdate = $action.dateFormatter.getCurrentDateTime() ) ## Get todays date
        #set ($thour = $tdate.replaceAll(".* ([0-9]+):..", "$1") )  ## Extract the current hour value from the datetime string
        #if (!$thour.matches("8|9|10|11|12|13|14"))
            #if ($action.latestVersionsOfAttachments.size() > 1)
                <a id="download-all-link" href="$req.contextPath/pages/downloadallattachments.action?pageId=$pageId" title="$action.getText('download.all.desc')">$action.getText('download.all')</a>
            #end
        #else
            Download all attachments option only available outside of business hours.
        #end  ## $thour.matched end
```

This is the block of code to change:

```
    #if ($latestVersionsOfAttachments.size() > 0)
        #set ($contextPath = "$req.contextPath/pages/viewpageattachments.action?pageId=$pageId&sortBy=$sortBy&")
        #set ($sortPathPrefixHtml = "?pageId=$page.id&sortBy=")
        #set ($showActions = "true")
        #set ($old = "true")
        #set ($attachmentHelper = $action)
        #parse("/pages/includes/attachments-table.vm")
        #if ($action.latestVersionsOfAttachments.size() > 1)
             <a id="download-all-link" href="$req.contextPath/pages/downloadallattachments.action?pageId=$pageId" title="$action.getText('download.all.desc')">$action.getText('download.all')</a>
        #end
        #pagination($action.paginationSupport $contextPath)
    #else
        $action.getText('currently.no.attachments')
    #end
```

Here is the change so that the Download All link is only displayed outside of business hours:

```
    #if ($latestVersionsOfAttachments.size() > 0)
        #set ($contextPath = "$req.contextPath/pages/viewpageattachments.action?pageId=$pageId&sortBy=$sortBy&")
        #set ($sortPathPrefixHtml = "?pageId=$page.id&sortBy=")
        #set ($showActions = "true")
        #set ($old = "true")
        #set ($attachmentHelper = $action)
        #parse("/pages/includes/attachments-table.vm")
        ## Only display Download All link during business hours ##
        #set ($tdate = $action.dateFormatter.getCurrentDateTime() ) ## Get todays date
        #set ($thour = $tdate.replaceAll(".* ([0-9]+):..", "$1") )  ## Extract the current hour value from the datetime string
        #if (!$thour.matches("8|9|10|11|12|13|14"))
            #if ($action.latestVersionsOfAttachments.size() > 1)
                <a id="download-all-link" href="$req.contextPath/pages/downloadallattachments.action?pageId=$pageId" title="$action.getText('download.all.desc')">$action.getText('download.all')</a>
            #end
        #else
            Download all attachments option only available outside of business hours.
        #end  ## $thour.matched end
```